# NameError in TensorFlow tutorial while using the Retrained Model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following TensorFlow for Poets [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#5). paragraph about Using the Retrained Model.

When I'm trying to run Python file which provided in the tutorial

```
python /tf_files/label_image.py /tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

Code of the file label_image.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

I got an error:

```
 File "/tf_files/label_image.py", line 4, in <module>
    image_path=sys.argv[1]
    NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you get it working finally? :)

Comment: @soprof Yeah, import sys - helps me!

Comment: Did you try training it with your own categories/examples?

Comment: @soprof No, but according to the tutorial, you just need to change pictures in the folders, where you have folders with flowers, and put your own categories and pictures there, and then retrain the model.

Comment: I understand; was just interested if you came up with any fun to use cases. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try with `import sys` ?